# How can i use if then else in hbs backbone template file, i m using handelsbar for template

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

i want to use if then else in hbs file, if `{{NumLikes}}` is greater than `0` then 1st image else 2nd image, so how i can use if then else in hbs template file using backbone.js.
I am using handelsbar for template.

```
<div>
        < div class="comm-tab-row">
            <div class="post-left-panel">
                <div class="post-image-container">
                 <img src="{{UserImageURL}}" alt="" class="post-image"  /></br>     
                <% if ({{NumLikes}} = 0) { %>
                    <img src="images/myCommunity/like@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >               
                <% } else { %>
                    <img src="images/myCommunity/liked@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >
                <%  } %>            
                ({{NumLikes}})          
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div class="post-body">
                <h5 class="comm-tab-heading">
                    <span class="navigate-screen" id="{{Id}}" style="text-decoration:underline;">
                        {{UserName}}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                         - &nbsp;
                    </span>
                    <span>
                       {{format_date Time ""}}
                    </span>
                </h5>
                {{Message}}
                </div>
                <div class="comm-right-panel">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-follow" name = "follow-button">FOLLOW</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-comment" name = "comment-button">{{NumComments}} - COMMENT</a>
            </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. but now i m receiving this error.                                                                 Error: ifCond doesn't match if
var tmp = Error.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom helper for this, the standard `{{#if}}` will do the right thing with a zero. For example, this template:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#if a}}a{{else}}!a{{/if}}<br>
    {{#if b}}b{{else}}!b{{/if}}<br>
</script>
```

and this code:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t({
    a: 0,
    b: 1
}));
```

will give you `!a` and `b` as output. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tUAyZ/

Your template should say this:

```
{{#if NumLikes}}
    <img src="images/myCommunity/like@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >               
{{else}}
    <img src="images/myCommunity/liked@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write an helper as below, because comparing with a value is not directly supported by handlebars.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1,options) {
  if(v1 == 0) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And in your handlebar templates you need to use it as below

```
<div class="post-left-panel">
    <div class="post-image-container">
    <img src="{{UserImageURL}}" alt="" class="post-image"  /></br>     
    {{#ifCond NumLikes}}
        <img src="images/myCommunity/like@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >
    {{else}}
        <img src="images/myCommunity/liked@2x.png" width="20" height="19" id="like-btn" name = "like-Button" >
    {{/if}}
    ({{NumLikes}})          
    </div>
</div>
```